# To lock sql when multiple users trying to update details of different users

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application , we have list of students and we have staff login. When multiple staff logs in and try to edit two different student details , when a first user opens the page and second user opens page second both trying to update two different student details , on update , the first user data wont get update  while the second user data updates.When checked with the break point, at that time on first user update , it was taking student id of details opened by second user. Tried with Lock but before it could go to the stored procedure , value is changing. Any help appreciated.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: I think you have some static fields in your ASP.NET page. Bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe sounds simply like a bug (or bugs) in your code that handles this data.

The most common error here is the use of `static` members to hold data that is actually per-request. `static` means "per app-domain", so all requests share **the same fields**. Basically: don't do that.

It is not uncommon to find code that uses static as a mechanism to avoid having to pass data between places - because it can be plucked from nowhere. This is still using it very inappropriately. It will appear to work ok on a dev machine simply because you only usually have one concurrent user on a developer machine. Most people want a web site that scales to more than one user.

Search for any static members. If you find any (with the possible exception of configuration values that don't change during execution) then they are probably wrong.

You can also achieve the same errors by using cache or application-state inappropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using static variable/fields or opened two student info edit mode in two adjacent tabs and holding the editing studentId in Sessions.
When you open the second user in new tab, the first student id is overridden by the second, even when you go back to the student one tab and update (perform submit the details) it will be updated for the second user.

You avoid this  kind of issue by using `ViewState["StudentID"]` or Hidden fields because their scope is within the page.